# Requests Python module in QGIS return nontype or empty CSV

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, api, qgsfeaturerequest

I am using the Requests Python module to query a 3rd party API that returns a polygon of an address, the returned CSV returning only part of the header, while it is working fine when using the code outside of QGIS,
following are 2 screenshots and the code.

[image: qgis interface]

[image: Excel csv]

the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import requests
import os

sep = '&'
base_url = "https://property.melissadata.net/v4/WEB/LookupProperty?"
id_ = 'id=API_KEY'
patch_name = 't=test'
cols = 'cols=GrpAll'
format_ = 'format=JSON'
user_address = '13229 Alta Vista Way, Sylmar, CA'

url = base_url + id_ + sep + patch_name + sep + cols + sep + format_ \
               + sep + user_address

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

requests_data = response.text

requests_data = json.loads(requests_data)
final_request_data = pd.json_normalize(requests_data['Records'])
final_request_data.to_csv('final_request_data.csv')

csvpath = 'file:///final_request_data.csv' 
uri = '{}?type=csv&xField={}&yField={}&crs={}'.format(
csvpath, 'PropertyAddress.Longitude', 'PropertyAddress.Latitude', 'EPSG:4326')
iface.addVectorLayer(uri, 'final_request_data', 'delimitedtext')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work. I can't run/reproduce your code without an API key for the particular API you were using. I used the [geonames.org API](https://www.geonames.org) for a test.

---

In your screenshot, it looks like your file is not found. Try to use an absolute file path. I assume that is the issue. QGIS does not know where to search for `final_request_data.csv`.

```py
csvpath = "file:///final_request_data.csv"  # change to an absolute file path
```

---

Below my test code which works well.

I refactored my code slightly using `urllib.parse.urlencode` but this should not be your issue.

I am also using `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer` to add the layer but because of an issue with the coordinate system.

```json
import json
import requests
import urllib.parse
import pandas as pd

from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject
```

```py
CSV_FILE = r"D:\temp\geonames.csv"

BASE_URL = "http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearchJSON"
QUERY_PARAMETERS = {
    "formatted": True,
    "q": "Zurich",
    "maxRows": 10,
    "username": "demo", # you may have to register, demo user has limited requests/h
}

url = f"{BASE_URL}?{urllib.parse.urlencode(QUERY_PARAMETERS)}"

response = requests.request("GET", url)

requests_data = json.loads(response.text)

df = pd.json_normalize(requests_data.get("geonames"))

df.to_csv(CSV_FILE, encoding="utf-8-sig", index=False)

layer_params = {
    "xField": "lng",
    "yField": "lat",
}
layer_uri = f"file:///{CSV_FILE}?{urllib.parse.urlencode(layer_params)}"

crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(layer_uri, "geonames", "delimitedtext", crs=crs)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

When I used `iface.addVectorLayer`, it did work as well *but* somehow did my QGIS not recognize the coordinate system properly. It displays the points correctly but has a warning.

---

Using `iface.addVectorLayer`:

```py
layer_params = {
    "xField": "lng",
    "yField": "lat",
    "crs": "epsg:4326",
}
layer_uri = f"file:///{CSV_FILE}?{urllib.parse.urlencode(layer_params)}"

iface.addVectorLayer(layer_uri, "geonames", "delimitedtext")
```

Comment: Thank you, Thomas, I have edited the code and now I get the data from the API, but I can't add the polygon as a layer using iface.addVectorLayer(uri, 'test_csv', 'delimitedtext')
And there is no obvious reason for me

Comment: @KareemAlaraby have you tried using `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)` instead? See my example. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the API and cannot reproduce your problem. Sorry that I can't help more.

Comment: Thank you, it didn't work also I went for the option to install geopandas on qgis and I will use it to transform the csv into shp and try with this Thanks again